# Evolving a for loop to skip dict key and values that are not equal to

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, findall

**Background**

I have a structure as follows:

```
trash = [ {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/german/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}]
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/', 
          'title': 'Simply Recipes Food and Cooking Blog', 'rel': ['home']},]
```

As you can see, most the keys are `'href'` and most the values contain `'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/'`. It is those keys and values that do not conform to this naming convention that are the issue...

**Code:**
This code iterates through the structure and using `re.findall` takes the string value between `'recipes/'` and the proceeding `/` to create a new key name for it's corresponding value.

```
for x in trash:
    for y in x.values():
        txt = ''
        for i in re.findall("recipes/.*", y):
            txt += i
            title = txt.split('/')[1]
            print({title: y})
```

**Output:**
Providing I remove the `keys` and `values` that don't meet the naming convention of being named `'href'` and containing the string value of `'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/'` the code works fine, as shown below:

```
{'cuisine': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'}
{'cuisine': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/german/'}
{'season': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'}
{'type': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'}
{'ingredient': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}
```

**Issue:**
The issue with the code is that I get a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` if the structure has an keys and values that don't confirm to the naming convention in the code.
**Question:**
How would I evolve this code so it will skip any keys that aren't named `'href'` and if they are named `'href'`, will skip over if their values do not contain `'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in trash:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key != "href" or "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/" not in value:
            continue  # Move onto next iteration
        txt = ''
        for i in re.findall("recipes/.*", value):
            txt += i
            title = txt.split('/')[1]
            print({title: value})
```

You can iterate over the keys and values of the dictionaries with `dict.items()`. Then you can use `if` statements to check your conditions and `continue` if they are not met.

Comment: That was a very generous response ;the code looks great and the explanation was on-point. Sincerest thanks